# Unable to put lapack.so file inside rootfs

Tags: yocto, bitbake, lapack, recipe, rootfs

I'm trying to install **lapack** on my 64 bit ARMV8 board with yocto. I have lapack-3.9 bitbake recipe and it has been successfully built. It has successfully created libblas.so and liblapack.so inside image/usr/lib64 folder.

I added lapack to my **local.conf** . The problem is when i do

```
bitbake core-image-weston
```

I don't have these **.so** inside my rootfs. That is, inside /usr/lib64.
What am i missing here???
Below is my lapack_3.9.0.bb recipe-

```
SUMMARY = "Linear Algebra PACKage"
URL = "http://www.netlib.org/lapack"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=930f8aa500a47c7dab0f8efb5a1c9a40"

# Recipe needs FORTRAN support (copied from conf/local.conf.sample.extended)
# Enabling FORTRAN
# Note this is not officially supported and is just illustrated here to
# show an example of how it can be done
# You'll also need your fortran recipe to depend on libgfortran
#FORTRAN_forcevariable = ",fortran"
#RUNTIMETARGET_append_pn-gcc-runtime = " libquadmath"

DEPENDS = "libgfortran"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "0b251e2a8d5f949f99b50dd5e2200ee2"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "106087f1bb5f46afdfba7f569d0cbe23dacb9a07cd24733765a0e89dbe1ad573"

EXTRA_OECMAKE = " -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON "
OECMAKE_GENERATOR = "Unix Makefiles"

inherit cmake pkgconfig
EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD = "1"
```

- Also, when i try to add **lapack-dev** and **lapack-dbg** ipks to my local.conf, it only allows lapack-dbg but gives an error for lapack-dev -

  **ERROR:**

```
Collected errors:
 * Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/1:
 *   - nothing provides lapack = 3.9.0-r0 needed by lapack-dev-3.9.0-r0.aarch64
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing lapack-dev
```